# Customer Invoice form; generic lists; C#

Tags: c#

I am working on this project and was asked to write a code to connect data from InvoiceDB and CustomerDB to Form1.Cs. 
I am done with my code but somehow it did not work. When I run a program, the Listview in form1 could not get a data from classes.
I would like to ask for some help from experts.
Thank you.

My code Form1.cs

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            **//Get data from Invoice and Customer Class**
            List<Invoice> invoiceList = InvoiceDB.GetInvoices();
            List<Customer> customerList = CustomerDB.GetCustomers();

            **//Query expression**
            var invoices = from invoice in invoiceList
                               join customer in customerList
                               on invoice.CustomerID equals customer.CustomerID
                                orderby customer.Name, invoice.InvoiceTotal descending
                           select new {customer.Name, invoice.InvoiceID, invoice.InvoiceDate, invoice.InvoiceTotal};

            **//Executes the query**
           string customerName = " ";
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var invoice in invoices)
            {
                if (invoice.Name != customerName)
                {
                    lvInvoice.Items.Add(invoice.Name);
                    customerName = invoice.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvInvoice.Items.Add(" ");
                }
                lvInvoice.Items[i].SubItems.Add(invoice.InvoiceID.ToString());
                lvInvoice.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(invoice.InvoiceDate).ToShortDateString());
                lvInvoice.Items[i].SubItems.Add(invoice.InvoiceTotal.ToString("C"));
                i += 1;
            }
    }
    }
```

CustomerDB Class

```
public static class CustomerDB
{

    private const string Dir = @""; 
    private const string Path = Dir + "CustomersX23.txt";

    public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        StreamReader textIn = new StreamReader(
            new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]);
            customer.Name = columns[1];
            customers.Add(customer);
        }

        textIn.Close();
        return customers;
    }
```

InvoiceDB class

```
public static class InvoiceDB
{

    private const string Dir = @"";
    private const string Path = Dir + "Invoices.txt";

    public static List<Invoice> GetInvoices()
    {
        List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>();

        StreamReader textIn = new StreamReader(
            new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            invoice.InvoiceID = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]);
            invoice.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(columns[1]);
            invoice.InvoiceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(columns[2]);
            invoice.ProductTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[3]);
            invoice.SalesTax = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[4]);
            invoice.Shipping = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[5]);
            invoice.InvoiceTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[6]);
            invoices.Add(invoice);
        }

        textIn.Close();
        return invoices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the ListView is in Detail mode you should define [ColumnHeaderCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx) adding the columns that you want to display in the ListView. 
Without defining the ColumnHeaderCollection the ListView will appear to be empty

This remarks from MSDN explain it

> The Columns property returns a collection that contains the
>   ColumnHeader objects that are displayed in the ListView control.
>   ColumnHeader objects define the columns that are displayed in the
>   ListView control when the View property is set to Details. Each column
>   is used to display subitem information for each item in the ListView.
>   For more information about how to manipulate the items in the
>   collection, see ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection.

You should add the columns to your ListView, something like this

```
lvInvoice.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvInvoice.Columns.Add("ID", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvInvoice.Columns.Add("Date", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvInvoice.Columns.Add("Total", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

There are [many overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnheadercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Add method, choose the most appropriate for your task

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but I already added columns in the design form. Any others opinion?

Comment: Then I suggest to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the methods that read your data and after the linq query that joins them. Verify if you have the required data.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem copying your code and I have the same problem until I defined the columns in code (before adding elements to the ListView and displaying it) Not sure at this point if your problem is in the code shown. Try adding a _lvInvoice.Columns.Clear();_ and then add from code the columns.